# "ImportError: No module named exceptions" when running Celery

Tags: python, celery, importerror

I'm attempting to run a Django app that uses Celery and I'm receiving the following error:

```
    import djcelery
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/djcelery/__init__.py", line 25, in <module>
    from celery import current_app as celery  # noqa
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/celery/__compat__.py", line 135, in __getattr__
    module = __import__(self._object_origins[name], None, None, [name])
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/celery/_state.py", line 18, in <module>
    from celery.utils.threads import LocalStack
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/celery/utils/__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from celery.exceptions import CPendingDeprecationWarning, CDeprecationWarning
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/celery/exceptions.py", line 15, in <module>
    from billiard.exceptions import ( # noqa
ImportError: No module named exceptions
```

billiard is installed and the `exceptions` module does exist, and I'm able to import billiard.exceptions via Python's interactive prompt without issues. It seems that celery is failing to import billiard. Any ideas?

Comment: please check `sys.path` and make sure it can find billiard

Comment: It can. Like I said, I'm able to import billiard via Python's shell.

Comment: There may be another `billiard` on the path. Prior to import check `sys.path` like @dnozay suggests.

Comment: Did you find a solution? I'm running into this same issue.